# Single SSL certificate for all Subdomains

Tags: web-services, security, web, hosting, web-hosting

I would like to have only one secure socket layer certificate for all the sub domains created under that domain. Is there any way to achieve this other than wildcard secure socket layer.

Answer (score 5):

I think only way is *.domain.com and which is provided by wildcard certificate

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate

Comment: Thanks for you reply..Actually I have a application hosted on a sub domain like xyz.domainname.com...The configured ssl works fine in this case..Access to any of the subdomain is redirected to xyz.domainname.com...In this case im shown an error that my site is not trusted....How can I fix this..

Comment: The redirection is done properly to the application on  xyz.domainname.com but the subdomain name is not changed and so the ssl is not trusted.  

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could we have a link to the website to have a see? If not, what does it say about why it is not trusted.

Comment: @Prabu, you should edit your question. What is the user typing in their browser? This is only going to work if they're typing `http://abc.example.com` and you redirect to `https://xyz.example.com`.

Comment: @Murph  It shows an SSL Error,

You attempted to reach dsfsd.example.com, but instead you actually reached a server identifying itself as xyz.example.com. This may be caused by a misconfiguration on the server or by something more serious. An attacker on your network could be trying to get you to visit a fake (and potentially harmful) version of dsfsd.example.com.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @MarcusAdams Thanks for your reply. People try to access the site via Http://abc.example.com and is redirected to https://xyz.example.com..

Answer (score 2):

You can either use *.domainname.com(wildcard) or xyz.domainname.com(single domain) and just add other as subdomains or FQDNs as SANs eg: SANs (abc.domainname.com, mydomain.com)